# How do I validate both email and phone in the same field?

Tags: javascript, yup

I'm using [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) to validate my fields. I currently just have one field that should validate both `email` or `phone`. However I'm not entirely sure on how to do that. I currently have email validation working, but is it possible to validate both of these in one input? Here is what I have currently:

```
import yup from 'yup';

const schema = yup.object().shape({
    data: yup.string().email().required(),
});

export default schema;
```

Comment: yup don't have phone validation direclty

Comment: You need to directly validate in the function triggered by the onChange or onBlur event. There are two approaches you can take: 1) either using a regex to ensure only digits and a minimum/maximum length, or 2) using an external library to validate. libphonenumber-js is a light JS implementation of google's phone validation algorithm, I'd recommend using that library's `parsePhoneNumberFromString` function and `isValid` method.